# Excel: SEARCH function doesn't work with another worksheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to compare a column of data (each row separately) to a column in another worksheet and give a simple TRUE/FALSE, I tried declaring the list directly in the SEARCH function but it didn't work so I resorted to TEXTJOIN to make it easier for the SEARCH function but it still does not work.
I tested the function below in Google Sheets and it worked, in Excel 2016 it just gives an error `#NAME?`
Any idea why or is there another way to do this? To clarify, SEARCH function is the one not working, not the ISNUMBER

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,AnotherSheet!L3:L)))
```

Comment: Use `ISNUMBER(MATCH())` or `COUNTIF()>0`.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(AnotherSheet!L:L,A2)>0`.